# Get provider name from connection

Tags: c#, .net

I've used this code to get the provider name and factory from a connection:

```
public string GetFactory(IDbConnection connection) {
  string provider = connection.GetType().Namespace;
  return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for Sql Ce (compact edition) as it does not contain the version information. I think this is a general problem when multiple versions of the same driver is installed.

Exmaple: the code above will use the provider "System.Data.SqlServerCe" but the real name from DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses() says "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5".

I cannot find any provider version property on the connection to concatenate with the name. Are there any solution to this or another approches?

Comment: Usually you do opposite thing - get connection from factory

Comment: Correct, this code is taken out of context. It is used in a DAL to retrieve objects from a database. The factory is mandatory if the application creates multiple connections, or needs to create a new connection after the original connection has been disposed.