# How can I get the "providerName" used for a specific DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

In the `OnModelCreating` function I was able to get the `DbConnection` object used for this `DbContext` instance, but how to get the `providerName` ?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

     // this.Database.Connection ==> this returns the DbConnection object
     // but I couldn't find the providerName
}
```

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686744) but it's unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IsSqlServer (IsXxx) method: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/24b9aa1d2e14fe2e737255ede9b2a7a623fcf2af/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L31